# How to excute the below code? from CanCan Abilities in Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cancan, cancancan

I got this from [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Abilities-in-Database), but I don't know where to put and how I will execute this.

I tried to create class and run this thru console (`rails c`) but it is not working.

```
def setup_actions_controllers_db

  write_permission("all", "manage", "Everything", "All operations", true)

  controllers = Dir.new("#{Rails.root}/app/controllers").entries
  controllers.each do |controller|
    if controller =~ /_controller/
      foo_bar = controller.camelize.gsub(".rb","").constantize.new
    end
  end
  # You can change ApplicationController for a super-class used by your restricted controllers
  ApplicationController.subclasses.each do |controller|
    if controller.respond_to?(:permission)  
      clazz, description = controller.permission
      write_permission(clazz, "manage", description, "All operations")
      controller.action_methods.each do |action|
        if action.to_s.index("_callback").nil?
          action_desc, cancan_action = eval_cancan_action(action)
          write_permission(clazz, cancan_action, description, action_desc)
        end
      end
    end
  end

end

and so on ...
```

Kindly help me on this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a `rake` task with that code and run that task afterwards in order to populate your newly created `Permission` table. To create a rake task you need to add the file `<newtask>.rake` in `lib/tasks/<newtask>.rake`.

Comment: Do you know how to create a rake task and run it?

Comment: Yeah. I already tried that. I created `namespace :permissions do
  task :exec => :environment do
    setup_actions_controllers_db
  end
end` and run like this `rake permissions:exec`

Comment: I suppose you have a `permissions` table as described in the article. When you run the task, what did you have as errors?

Comment: I manage to run this now. Thanks. But the code is not working. I will debug it instead. Thanks